# compiling and executing java from bash script

Tags: java, bash

I'm trying to compile my java code using a bash script. I need to pass in arguments too, which I'm getting from another file in the same directory. My script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MYID="$(cat $(pwd)/my.id)"
eval javac src/main/java/foo/bar.java "$MYID"
```

but it thinks of my argument as another java file for compilation and gives me the error:

```
Class names, 'abc123', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
```

P.S. abc123 is the only id in the my.id file I need to pass.

Please help me make this work, I have been looking for solutions the whole day. :(

**edit: This was a stupid question.
I just realized I was passing in arguments at the wrong place. I figured it out. thankyou!**

Comment: What should the compiler do with the ID? You maybe want to pass it when you start the program?

Comment: Actually what do you want to do? use javac --help to know the options that are to be used. Also what is the utility of this script if only `bar.java` is to be compiled everytime?

Comment: It will generate another java file based on this id. After which I'll compile another class with that generated java file.

Comment: *What* will generate another file based on this id? Javac will not generate source files. Maybe your bar class does? In that case you shouldn't pass the argument to javac, but you should have a second line that runs your bar class and passes the argument to it

Comment: let me explain my code. i pass in an id to one of my classes, which helps me create another java class. I use that generated class with my main program.

Comment: Please [edit] your post instead of adding comments. (Note that "pass in an  id to one of my classes" still does not make much sense - possibly you expect something that does not really happen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way.  The `javac` command compiles programs.  That is it.  It doesn't generate source code.

Based on your comments it sounds like you should be doing something like this:

```
javac foo/Bar.java
java foo.Bar $(cat my.id) > foo/Baz.java
javac foo/Baz.java
```

This assumes that `foo.Bar` is some kind of generator program that knows how to generate java source code.

In reality, I expect that what you are really trying to do is some kind of source-code template expansion.  There are simpler and / or more flexible ways to do that that writing a bespoke Java program to do it.  (For example, use the "m4" utility.)

Comment: yes thankyou! i just realized how stupid my question was. lol